# How do I use a combination of event objects, eventlisteners, and child elements to create the amount of buttons the user selects from a prompt

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I am trying to use a combination of event objects, event listeners and child elements to create the amount of buttons a user selects from a list.

Full code for buttons and selections below

```
<div id=buttons>
        
How many buttons would you like?

<label>1 <input name=numberButtons type=radio value=1></label>
<label>2 <input name=numberButtons type=radio value=2></label>
<label>3 <input name=numberButtons type=radio value=3></label>
<label>4 <input name=numberButtons type=radio value=4></label>
<label>5 <input name=numberButtons type=radio value=5></label>
<label>6 <input name=numberButtons type=radio value=6></label>
<label>7 <input name=numberButtons type=radio value=7></label>
<label>8 <input name=numberButtons type=radio value=8></label>
    
</div>
     
<span id=done>Done</span>
```

The id=done is the button that is clicked to create said buttons

I tried creating a function but it did nothing.

Comment: Please share the code of the function you tried along with clarification of  "it did nothing": was it a silent failure, were there any errors reported on the console, or did it produce weird output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:checked` pseudo-class to get the selected radio input, then use a loop to create buttons (with `document.createElement`) and append them to a container element.

```js
const buttonsContainer = document.querySelector('#buttonsContainer');
document.querySelector('#done').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const numButtons = +document.querySelector('input[name=numberButtons]:checked')?.value || 0;
  buttonsContainer.replaceChildren();
  for (let i = 1; i <= numButtons; i++)
    buttonsContainer.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('button'), 
      { textContent : 'Button ' + i }));
});
```

```css
#buttonsContainer { margin-top: 10px; }
```

```html
<div id=buttons>
  How many buttons would you like?
  <label>1 <input name=numberButtons type=radio value=1></label>
  <label>2 <input name=numberButtons type=radio value=2></label>
  <label>3 <input name=numberButtons type=radio value=3></label>
  <label>4 <input name=numberButtons type=radio value=4></label>
  <label>5 <input name=numberButtons type=radio value=5></label>
  <label>6 <input name=numberButtons type=radio value=6></label>
  <label>7 <input name=numberButtons type=radio value=7></label>
  <label>8 <input name=numberButtons type=radio value=8></label>
</div>
<button id=done>Done</button>
<div id="buttonsContainer"></div>
```